# Have error on android 5.0. but not on android 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-layout, runtime-error, layout-inflater

When I tried to install my app to android 5.0. I got this errors: 
Can you give me advice from this logcat? What is should do?

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 24
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:401)
```

... 65 more[image]

2-nd part:
[image]

[image]

Comment: please share the layout file.